# How to customize python unittest tests output?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am working in the database domain. Few days back I started working on unit testing using python's most popular package i.e. `unittest`. I am totally new to python unittest.
I want to test some database opreations like Add/update/delete with different database servers. 
I want the final test result as below

```
sample result
-------------------
==============
server 1: 20 passed 10 failed
server 2: 10 passed 20 failed
==============
```

and so on...

My current class structure is

```
Class DB_Test(uniittest.Testcase):
    def setUpClass(self):
         <generate predata(like create server, connect to server)>
    def runTest(self):
         for server in server_list:
               add_db(<server_data>,<db_data>)
    def tearDown(self):
         <clean the predata>
```

So, How to customise the code so that I can capture the test result serverwise? Now its showing default test result with ok & fail.

Comment: You could launch the tests for each server and collect the `unittest.TestResult` object for each one. see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult)